# Unable to access SVN externally - Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

When I access the following URL on my machine https://svnserver:80/svn/web/domain.com I get the error:

```
<D:error>
  <C:error/>
  <m:human-readable errcode="2">
    Could not open the requested SVN filesystem
  </m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

The exact name of my respository is `domain.com`, I have https up and running, so any ideas why I can't access the repository?

My dav_svn.conf:

```
  <Location /svn/web>
        DAV svn
        SVNPath /var/svn-repos/web
  </Location>
  SVNParentPath /var/svn-repos/
```

My **dav_svn.conf SHOULD BE**:

```
  <Location /svn/web>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /var/svn-repos/web
  </Location>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTPS uses port 443 not 80.

Try `https://example.com/svn/web/domain.com`

Comment: When I use 443, I get the error I describe here: http://serverfault.com/questions/127386/local-server-accessible-via-https-with-80-but-not-without/127391#127391

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that SVNParentPath belongs within Location instead of SVNPath....

The docs within the dav_svn.conf file do not clearly show this.